# Ensure previous version of a cell is removed after 10 minutes

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

In Cassandra, I want to update a row to remove some sensitive data once the row has been processed.
A row has the following process.

1. Insert the record
2. Process the record (update it)
3. Set the row to processed and remove the sensitive data from one column of the row

I am aware that the update are not actually updating the data on disk by design of Cassandra. However, I want to ensure that after a not too long period the data is actually removed from disk. There is no row removed from this table explicitly (with a CQL statement) only insert and update statements.

From what I understood, I have to use a relatively short `gc_grace_period`, like 10 minutes.

Could you tell me if this configuration would work? What is the impact of such strategy?

I am using Cassandra 3.11.1 and the table has a TTL of one day. About 100k to 1M records are inserted by day in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me answer this two part question :-

gc_grace_seconds is the time Cassandra has to wait before it can clean up the SSTables that have tombstone data (caused by TTL/Deletes). So here in your case, the table has a TTL of 1 day and by default gc_grace_seconds is 864000 (seconds) = 10days. Which means that the data that has expired in a day waits for another 10days (by default) before getting cleaned up.

The reason default gc_grace_seconds is high is to ensure that during explicit deletes, if any node in the cluster was down, the deletes (tombstones) get propagated as the node comes back up. In other words to avoid zombie data.

In your case, since there isn't any explicit deletes and only tombstones its safe to have a smaller value for gc_grace_seconds say 90000 (25hours).

*Another riskier option, is to set gc_grace_seconds to zero if guaranteed that the application would never do explicit deletes and rely on TTL only. Setting it to zero has the advantage of no tombstones in the system. Data gets purged as soon as its TTLed*

Second Part of the question :

In order to expire the column within 10 minutes of processing, we can set column level TTL as follows. Below I'm suggesting a shorter gc_grace_seconds along with TWCS which would help to evict this row within 10 + 1min and wouldn't cause tombstone pressure.

Update CQL to set column level TTL

```
UPDATE test USING TTL 600 
  SET status = 'PROCESSED' 
  WHERE primary_key = ? ;
```

Additionally, regarding the table compaction strategy :-

I'm assuming the rows are being processed sequentially (or in other words this table being treated as a queue). So cleaner way to handle this situation would be to use "Time Window Compaction Strategy". Generally its recommended to keep the number of TimeWindow slices to less than 50 slices.

The command would be

```
CREATE TABLE test (
........
) WITH 
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 60
    AND default_time_to_live = 86400
    AND compaction = {'compaction_window_size': '30', 
                      'compaction_window_unit': 'MINUTES', 
                      'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.TimeWindowCompactionStrategy'}
```

This setup would give us the following guarantees :

- Data older than 30 Minutes stops being compacted, lowering I/O consumption. Queries targeting rows within a 30 minute time range will mostly hit a limited number of SSTables in case compaction is up to date
- Using TTL inserts, tombstones get purged by file deletion (in this case, shortly after 1 days and 1 minute after the original write)
- Data sent out of their original time window through hints or repairs are compacted with SSTables of the current window only, preventing write amplification
- Maximum compaction overhead on disk is 50% of the last created bucket
- Disk space usage growth is easily predictable

A nice read on [TWCS](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/12/08/TWCS-part1.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just got some questions, why is it riskier to have a grace period of 0? It looks like a queue but I cannot garanteed that all records are processed in the right order (some elements can be retried) and I thought it excludes TWCS. Is it the case or not? I heard that TTL by column uses tombstone and can degrade the performance, is it the case and a problem for this use case?

Comment: As long as there isn't explicit DELETE cql and only TTLs then setting gc_grace_seconds low (like 1min) wouldn't be a problem. Its riskier only when there are deletes. Processing of the rows in order shouldn't matter, as long as they are done within 24hour TTL window. TWCS shouldn't be a constraint. TTL by column degrades performance for tables that have higher gc_grace_seconds (like default 10days). In the example above we have it set it to 1min in combination with TWCS, so it wouldn't impact performance for this particular case.

Comment: When you mean " Processing of the rows in order shouldn't matter, as long as they are done within 24hour TTL window", it is the compaction window and not the TTL right? Thank very much for your in-deph answer!!

Comment: The TTL of 1 day, would make the data expire by 24hours. So your data would be gone if it isn’t processed within a day.